# Why I am getting a SIGSEGV error for this program?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a reverse Polish printer on an online coding website which can perform the following operation-

Inputs:

(a+(b*c))

((a+b)*(z+x))

((a+t)*((b+(a+c))^(c+d)))
Outputs:

abc*+

ab+zx+*

at+bac++cd+^*

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char pop(int t);
void push(int c, int t);
char a[100][400];
int main()
{
    int z;
    scanf("%d", &z);

    int i = 0;
    int q = z;
    while (q-- > 0)
    {

        scanf("%s",&a[i][0]);
        int t;
        for (t = 0; t < strlen(a[i]); t++)    //loop to put the values and signs in the 2 stacks
        {
            if ((a[i][t] == '*') || (a[i][t] == '+') || (a[i][t] == '-') || (a[i][t] == '^'))
            {
                push(a[i][t], 2);


            }

            else if (a[i][t] == ')')
            {
                int y = pop(2);
                push(y, 1);

            }

            else
            {
                push(a[i][t], 1);

            }
        }
        int k = 0;
        char c;
        while ((c = pop(1)) !='\0')    //loop to put elements in the array v
        {

            if (c != '(')
            {

                a[i][k++] = c;

            }
        }
        a[i][k--] = '\0';
        int m;
        for (m=0; m != k; m++, k--)     
        {
            char t = a[i][m];
            a[i][m] = a[i][k];
            a[i][k] = t;
        }



    }
    int p;
    for (p = 0; p <z ; p++)   
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
char ac[400];
char as[400];
int ic = 0;
int is = 0;
void push(int c,int t)
{
    if (t == 1 && ic != 400)
        ac[ic++] = c;
    else if (t == 2 && is != 400)
        as[is++] = c;
}
char pop(int t)
{
    if (t == 1 && ic != 0)
        return ac[--ic];
    if (t == 2 && is != 0)
        return as[--is];
    return '\0';
}
```

On compiling this code I am getting a SIGSEGV error.I don't know whats the mistake in this code.Please help

Comment: Compiling results in a segfault, not running the result?

Comment: If you get that on compiling then there's something wrong with your compiler (which sounds highly unlikely).

Comment: @barak manos Actually the code works fine with local compiler and produce the same output as given above but fails when I submit it to the compiler of the website.

Comment: Put spaces between your lines of code.  It makes it more readable.    Debuggers are good, check out `gdb`. @Daniel: I totally agree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are getting SIGSEGV. However, I see couple of errors in your code.

1. You are using `scanf("%s",&a[i][0]);` but `i` is never changed from its initial value of `0`. I suggest changing

   ```
   while (q-- > 0)
   ```

   to

   ```
   for ( i = 0; i < z; ++i )
   ```
2. You are printing `a[i]` even though you are using `p` as the for loop index in

   ```
   for (p = 0; p <z ; p++)   
      printf("%s\n",a[i]);
   ```

   That's easily fixed by changing the second line to:

   ```
      printf("%s\n",a[p]);
   ```
3. In your input, you didn't include the value of `z`. I hope that is an error in creating the post and that you have the value of `z` in your input.

With those changes, I don't see any problem in my environment. I tested using gcc 4.7.3. Not sure fixing those will fix the problem in your environment.